# How to find out the name of the caller object during a function?

Tags: c#, winforms, function, linklabel

I'm trying to create a "list" using linklabels to identify attachments (in a mail client). So, I've this to create the links:

```
Label newLabel = new LinkLabel();
newLabel.Name = "anexo" + Convert.ToString(anexos_file.Count); //anexos_file is a list where all the attachments Paths exist
newLabel.Text = Path.GetFileName(file);
newLabel.Left = bt_anexos.Left;
newLabel.Top = label2.Top;
newLabel.Width = 150;
newLabel.AutoSize = true;
newLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(Click_anexo); //Click_anexo is the name of the function
```

Now I need to know how do I make a function that, when I click the link, deletes the link itself.

So, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Click_anexo(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{

}
```

Object `sender` parameter contains information about the control which fired this event. Cast `sender` as Label

```
LinkLabel lbl = (LinkLabel)sender;
```

and use it

```
lbl.Visible = false;
```

I think making it invisible is as good as deleted.

Comment: EventArguments ? try EventArgs

Comment: To delete I just add: this.Controls.RemoveByKey(lbl.Name);
But thanks!

Comment: @JoãoBorrego Make sure you remove the handler when you delete the Control

Comment: @MarkHall: Why delete Handler? Who will call the event when control is deleted or not visible?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal The control will not be garbage collected because there are still references to it after it has been deleted, leading to a perceived memory leak. This is only when you manually add an eventhandler to a control. So if you add it -- remove it

Answer (score 2):

in the `Click_anexo` delegate you have to have `sender` parameter.

That parameter is of `object` type, but it is actually the control that raised that event.

Just cast it to the type you need and you done.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to your statement and to clarify some of my comments.

> To delete I just add: this.Controls.RemoveByKey(lbl.Name);

All you are doing here is removing your created control from its ControlCollection. The Control is still present and if you are creating a lot of these they will still be hanging around in memory. If you plan to reuse these controls then this fine, but if they are just for a onetime use you will be causing a memory leak.  The way I would do it would be remove the eventhandler and dispose of the object like this:

```
private void Click_anexo(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkLabel lbl = (LinkLabel)sender;
    lbl.Click -= new EventHandler(Click_anexo);
    lbl.Dispose();
}
```